# How to rename ngModel in AngularJS directive "require"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have this simple AngularJS directive:

```
<my-directive ng-model="name"></my-directive>
```

where I would like to change "ng-model" attribute to "model"... but I'm bit lost on how to pass it to the "require" option in the directive.
Here is the directive full code:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$render = function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue('StackOverflow');  
                }, 5000);                
            };
        }
    };
});
```

and here a fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/cg2enqj2/1/

can someone please help me to understand how (and if) it could be possible?

thank you very much!

Comment: the first param scope is preety much ng-model... So just change that to model

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the functionality of ng-model without calling it that. Can you explain why you can't just use ng-model?

Answer (score 1):

So you want your directive to update the parent controller? You shouldn't need ngModel to do this. The controller is designs to store values to display in the front end and contain the operations to get and set them. If you want to have a directive update the parent element, you should do it using a service/factory.

However, than can be a little over designed for simply moving a few values between screen elements. I prefer to have my scope accessible from the directives, usually just to read values, and then have the controller also handle the updating but call it from the directive. This may be a mortal sin in the Angular world but it works neatly for me.

In this example I stripped ngModel from your directive, and added a button that calls an update from a button I added to the template of the directive.

https://jsfiddle.net/jimmeyotoole/13kfdq8x/1/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
  return {
    replace: true,
    template : '<div><p> directive value = {{name}}</p> <button ng-click="activate()">Activate!</button><p>example private {{privatevar}}</p>',
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.privatevar="ZZZZ";
    }
   }
  });

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.name = 'Superman';
  $scope.activate = function () {
    $scope.name = "I'm no Superman";
  };
});
```

Comment: `replace: true` directives are deprecated since AngularJS 1.3.

Comment: Not exactly... and the fault is mine... as I commented above to Miszy I completely forget to explain that I'd need to access my model controller inside the link function without to have my html attribute named as "ng-model" but for example "model".

Answer (score 1):

It's a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You don't need `ngModel` in this code at all, so your question is all incorrect. You're basically asking about the wrong thing.

What you want to do is to communicate between the outer scope and the directive using directive's attributes. That's totally doable but instead of using `ngModel`, you can simply use `scope` attribute on the directive configuration object:

```
scope: {
    model: '='
}
```

and then in the directive's linking function:

```
$timeout(function () {
    scope.model = 'lol';
}, 1000);
```

The result is this: https://jsfiddle.net/s2f5jbrd/1/

Moreover, if you update to AngularJS 1.5 the syntax gets even cleaner thanks to the `.component` function. After applying all the good practices (component, bindings, controller, controller as) here is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/s2f5jbrd/4/

Comment: Thank you Miszy, you are probably right about XY problem, and I'm sorry about it! :(
Trying to clean my example for explain better my situation I completely forgot to specify that I need to access my model controller inside the link function; I've tried to change my fiddle to show what I need: https://jsfiddle.net/cg2enqj2/17/ this could actually work if I rename "model" to "ng-model" in my html, but I would know if it could be possible to have the model controller inside the link function without have the "ng-model" attribute in html but, for example named it as "model".

Answer (score 0):

After a bit research I found the way to get the ngModel controller of a child element of my directive.
Here is another directive as example where the model has a non-standard "ng-model" name but just "model": https://plnkr.co/edit/UgeYT6tbVpMal7KbPNDC?p=preview

```
function lgDate($compile, $filter) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                model: "=",
            },
            compile: compile
        };

        return directive;

        function compile(element, attrs) {
            return {
                pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var template = '<input ng-model="model" ng-keyup="keyup($event.keyCode)" ui-mask="99/99/9999" ' +
                                   'ng-pattern="/(\\d{4}(?!\\d))?([2-9]\\d{3}|1[8-9]\\d{2}|17[6-9]\\d|175[3-9])/" type="text" ';

                    if (element.attr('class')) {
                        template += 'class="' + attrs.class + '" ';
                        element.removeClass(attrs.class);
                    }

                    if (element.attr('name')) {
                        template += 'name="' + attrs.name + '" ';
                        element.removeAttr('name');
                    }

                    if (element.attr('required')) {
                        template += 'required ';
                        element.removeAttr('required');
                    }

                    template += '/>';

                    element.html(template);
                    element.removeClass(attrs.class);

                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                },
                post: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    var ctrl = element.find('input').controller('ngModel');

                    ctrl.$formatters.push(function (data) { // model - view
                        data = $filter('date')(data, 'ddMMyyyy');
                        return data;
                    });

                    ctrl.$parsers.push(function (data) { // view - model
                        var year = data.substr(-4);
                        var month = data.substr(2, 2);
                        var day = data.substr(0, 2);

                        data = (year && month && day) ? year + '-' + month + '-' + day + 'T00:00:00.000Z' : '';
                        return data;
                    });

                    scope.keyup = function (key) {
                        if (key === 68) { // D key
                            scope.model = new Date().toJSON();
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
```